# Perform scp-then-ssh in one connection

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, script, scp

Both at work and at home I tend to do the following very often:

```
$ scp "SomeScriptIJustCreatedOrModified.sh" some-server:
$ ssh some-server ./SomeScriptIJustCreatedOrModified.sh arguments
```

And sometimes this variation too:

```
$ scp "SomeScriptIJustCreatedOrModified.sh" some-server:/tmp
$ ssh some-server -t sudo -u other_user /tmp/SomeScriptIJustCreatedOrModified.sh arguments
```

The thing is, the server is often in a different country and the SSH handshake usually takes at least a couple seconds --- and this apparent short wait can get old quickly, as well as get in the way for long lists of servers. Not only that, I have been berated before for making suspiciously quick sucessive SSH connections.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Make an alias in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: @Adam one connection, not one command.

Comment: Look into using controlmaster, it opens one connection to the server and while that connection is open any future ssh or scp connections use that same connection and do not require you to enter your credentials. http://puppetlabs.com/blog/speed-up-ssh-by-reusing-connections

Comment: My .ssh/config looks like this: http://pastebin.com/8SHV8g3k

Comment: Why don't you just stay logged in on the remote server instead of connecting every time?

Comment: @jjlin Because I usually want to run that script in multiple servers. When it's meant to be run in a single server only I just run Vim there and don't bother keeping a local file.

Comment: @Ekevoo submitted. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ControlMaster` opens a single ssh connection, and allows future `ssh` and `scp` connections to go through the same connection, so there is no need to provide the password again, or wait for the connection to open.

Here is an example of how to setup `controlmaster`: [Speed Up SSH by Reusing Connections](https://puppetlabs.com/blog/speed-up-ssh-by-reusing-connections).

Edit your `.ssh/config` file to include the lines:

```
Host hostname                                                                                                          
    User username                                                                                                  
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist 600
```

Where `hostname` and `username` are replaced with the appropriate information.

`ControlPersist` uses seconds by default, but you can use `10m` for 10 minutes for example. It can also be `yes`, in which case there is no timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access on the server, you could always use an sftp client like ExpanDrive to mount your remote home directory on your local machine. Then you can just write your script locally in a text editor and save it to the locally-mounted remote machine.

At that point, it'll be on the server, and all you have to do is ssh into it and run it. As long as you keep your sftp and ssh connections open, you can save and run as many scripts as you want, all day long, and you'd only have to connect once for sftp and once for ssh.

Just keep in mind that with this workflow, every time you save you'll be writing to remote the server, and it'll only write as fast as OS and network limitations allow (i.e., it's going to be slower than writing locally).

Comment: Thanks, but it's a good solution for a single server scenario only.

Comment: You can connect to multiple servers simultaneously in Expandrive. For ssh, you can use screen or tabs in your terminal to open multiple connections at once.